# How does Eve's deflecting the Ghost's question identify the Ghost's Achilles heel?

Tags: killing-eve

I'm asking about [this post](https://old.reddit.com/r/KillingEve/comments/bk580t/killing_eve_s02e05_smell_ya_later_discussion/emgz6ph/) based on *Killing Eve* S2E5:

> Not to mention The Ghost flat out asking Eve if she’s ever wanted to know what it feels like to kill. And Eve doesn’t confirm or deny that (like yeah, they’re being recorded in the interrogation room).
>
> But it’s telling that this is the question which piques Eve’s interest. She declared that The Ghost was as boring as an accountant and that she could never compare to Villanelle in literally the previous scene. The comes this question all of a sudden, and what does Eve do?
>
> **She deflects it onto Villanelle, which is how she identifies The Ghost’s fracture point. [emboldening mine]**

The embolded sentence doesn't unravel how the deflection helped Eve.

Comment: Are you asking for us to explain some rando's Reddit post? Have you tried just asking the guy who posted it *in* that Reddit thread?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't watched season 2 yet, but my educated guess (from watching a lot of TV series) is that Eve (or the viewer) sees a weakness in Ghost by not answering Ghost directly. Perhaps this is when Eve figures out who Ghost is, because asking that kind of question tells Eve what she is truly interested in, killing and knowing other killers! By asking Eve this, she exposes her true intent/interests...

Or perhaps that Ghost's interest in Eve's motivation to ever want to kill is some kind of tell (not just to Eve, but the audience) that strings the three characters (Eve, Ghost, Villanelle) together in a unique way...

If Ghost is counter to Villanelle in disposition, then Eve's own careful deflection mirrors Ghost's subtle meticulous nature, but yet mentioning(?) Villanelle, a character who has flare for the dramatic and is often reckless, puts Eve perfectly dead center between the personalities or dispositions these two opposing assassins, being careful and perhaps reckless at the same time.

---

My guess is that is what this reddit comment is really about, that this simple scene could reach so far and have so much irony and reflection.